# linearly dependent variable in stepwise regression

Tags: regression

When we find that there is a variable linearly dependent with other variables(i.e. getting a NA coefficient in the full model using lm()).

Is it a good idea to just simply drop that variable or is there any other method to address that?

Or may be we can just ignore it and continue the stepwise regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have perfect linear relationships between your predictor variables one of two things happen. Your software throws an error OR it will drop one of the variables and proceed.

The solution in either case is simple. Drop one variable and execute, you lose no information.

The harder problem occurs when they are not perfectly related. In that case you would need to understand how to deal with multicollinearity while performing regression.

The good news however is that multicollinearity doesn't affect your model's predictive performance. However, if you are trying to interpret the model coefficients it will be misleading.